# Start application automatically once an event is received

Tags: android, service, estimote

In my application I'm using the [Estimote Beacon](http://estimote.com/) API. In order to start the ranging service, the user must start the application (the most obvious thing...) but, i was wondering if it were possible to avoid this user interaction by automating the start of the application.

A rough idea could be:

Keep the estimote ranging service running even if the application is closed. 
As soon as a beacon is detected, generate an `Intent` broadcast that will be captured by a `BroadcastReceiver` that in turn will start the Main Activity (maybe a notification could be sent to the user and the activity remains hidden).

1) Is that possible?
2) Is it a correct design choice?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour is exactly what the [`Service`](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) class is for.

I use this solution for media players where a `Widget` can interact with the `Service` without the need for a full blown `Activity` to be created.

Comment: It could not be so easy. Maybe i don't know exactly how to do it. I want to avoid to explicitly open the application.

Comment: If you don't open the application you will have no `Context` to launch an `Intent` from, you at least need a `Widget` which can be set to periodically launch and perform a simple task. For anything more complicated a `Service` would be advisable, and a darn site easier to debug.